# That's not ... is it? or is that?

Tags: grammar

That's not nice, is it?

or

That's not nice, is that?

Thanks guys. Tried googling, didn't work. Can't figure out a good way to search on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

This type of question is called a [tag question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question) (question tag in the UK). The most common form is a negated verb and a personal pronoun for positive statements and the reverse for negative ones.

> You're John Smith, aren't you?
>
> That's not John Smith, is it?

Using a demonstrative pronoun such as "this" or "that" in this construction instead of a personal pronoun would be highly non-idiomatic (i.e., wrong).